# GooglePlay: LVL: License: Validation Errors or Failures: LicenseCheckerCallback: com.google.android.vending.licensing

Tags: android, google-play, licensing, android-lvl

My inbox has been flooded this morning by users getting license validation errors for one of my paid apps. The licensing on the app has worked fine for the past 5 years or so.

Unfortunately I've not been able to reproduce the issue...

It uses the old LVL from Google package="com.google.android.vending.licensing"

```
private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
    // Means: GooglePlay believes this user is legitimate
    @Override
    public void allow(int x, int policyReason, String y) {
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try { mProgressDialog.dismiss(); mProgressDialog = null; } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        });

        // Update server
        Util.pingServer(getApplicationContext());
    }

    // Means: Google Play definitely thinks this version is a pirate version
    @SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
    public void dontAllow(int x, final int policyReason, String y) {
        EventLog.i(TAG, "don't Allow: " + policyReason);
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try { mProgressDialog.dismiss(); mProgressDialog = null; } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
                showGoogleLicenseDialog(policyReason == Policy.RETRY ? 1 : 0);
            }
        });
    }


    // Means: Developer has not setup licensing properly
    // ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED: not managed by Android Market (now called Google Play)
    // More specifically, the version X of your application is not uploaded or published in Google Play
    public void applicationError(final int errorCode) {
        EventLog.e(TAG, "applicationError: " + errorCode);

        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try { mProgressDialog.dismiss(); mProgressDialog = null; } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }

                // Developer mistake dialog
                String result = String.format(getString(R.string.application_error), errorCode);
                ActivityHelper.showToast(MainActivity.this, "License problem: App Error: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
    }
}
private final MyLicenseCheckerCallback mMyLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Google have dorked this up in production. It can be fixed by updating to GooglePlay store 10.7.19

[Latest Google Play Store 10.7.19 fixes LVL check](https://www.goandroid.co.in/latest-google-play-store-10-7-19-fixes-lvl-check/85760/)

Another article here:

[Google Play Store app licensing bug is putting developers in a horrible spot](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/07/03/google-play-store-app-licensing-bug-putting-developers-horrible-spot/)

A few Comments from users:
"Thanks, I side-loaded the playstore update and that seems to have fixed it."
"We gave up in the end and factory reset the phone.  This seems to have fixed the issue..."

The main issue at the moment is that not all users have access to the 10.7.19 update...

UPDATE:
Also received several comments like:
"On the Settings tab, I toggled the Notification Access off/on.  That seemed to wake it up.  Errors stopped."